# Pass extra parameters to jquery.Deferred callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

I want to pass some extra parameters to a jQuery.Deferred done callback, I'm doing it like this now:

```
//dfd gets defined here as the return value of jQuery.ajax

var me = this;
var selector = $("#selector");

dfd.done(function(response){
    me.updated(response, selector);
});
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? I thought I had read somewhere about a cleaner way to pass parameters without the need of an anonymous wrapper function but I can't for the life of me remember where I read it, or what I read. Google searches turned up nothing so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to pass something to `.done` callback you need to pass it in `.resolve`, for example

```
dfd.done( function(selector) {
   console.log( selector );
});
dfd.resolve( selector );
```

but in your case `dfd` is a `$.ajax` object and `.resolve` is called internally, so you have no control over it. Therefore the only way to do that is to use anonymous function and closure.

By the way: there is nothing unclean about this solution.

Comment: Ok excellent, it's probably a custom case I read about where the resolve was done by the programmer. Thanks!